# Downloading file with curl bash script

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to download big files with curl calls made by bash scripts' for loop.

```
for item in $LIST
   do
      i=$(expr $i + 1)
      echo "Downloading $i. $item"
      URL="${ROOT_URL_ODATA}/Products('$item')/\$value"
      [ "$VERBOSE" = "true" ] && show_text "$CURL_PREFIX -JO \"$URL\""      
      $CURL_PREFIX -JO "$URL"
   done
```

example url `https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products('931b6710-e6a5-4fd5-8314-16011e5515ab')/$value`

My command to download:

```
curl -gu user:passwd -JO 'https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products('931b6710-e6a5-4fd5-8314-16011e5515ab')/$value'
```

When running this it from script I get `curl -gu username:passwd: command not found` but when running it from bash I get that 100% of file is downloadaded in a second altought the file is about 4GB large...

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: [Don't use strings to store commands](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @TomFenech when I remove the string I get `syntax error near unexpected token `('` and when I separate only brackets with quotes I get that filename has no length and failed to write body. Altought it's the same as in their example script. [link](https://scihub.esa.int/twiki/do/view/SciHubUserGuide/BatchScripting#Open_Search)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my advice - removing the quotes doesn't make things any better (in fact it probably makes them worse). The issue is that you are building up a command containing several arguments but you're using a string to do it. Use an array instead, as explained in the link.

Comment: I acknowledge that it's a bad practise and may cause problems but it's not causing them in this case. When I brought the for loop out from the functions body then everything works fine just as it is.

Comment: The fact that you need to play these quoting games is caused by trying to store a command in a string. Once you need to start playing quoting games you have generally already lost. Stop using a string to store a command and you will likely have much better luck getting this to work correctly (as you will be able to simply and properly quote things).

Comment: Download the file and look into it using a text editor, maybe it's a `404`, `403` or even a `500`?